# C++ Windows add option to menu

Tags: c++, c, windows, api, menu

In windows, when you click the small icon in the upper left of the window, you get a menu with Move, Minimize, Maximize, and Close options.

Is there anyway I can add my own options to that menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.

[GetSystemMenu(hWindow, FALSE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/library/ms647985.aspx) gets you menu handle and you are free to modify it.

A nice way is to add a separator and append your additional items like "About...". ATL code snippet is here: http://www.assembla.com/code/roatl-utilities/subversion/nodes/trunk/FilterGraphSpy/GraphBuilderCallbackPropertySheet.h#ln1392 lines 1392-1396.